# Is it a good idea to store lengthy document chains in Google's Firestore?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

For example, I have a Project, which has multiple Project Map objects, which has multiple Map Events, which has multiple Objects.

So it would look like Project -> Project Map -> Map Event -> Objects. Also I have a many to many relationship with Users to Projects.

It seems a little deep to query easily for Firestore, but then I haven't been using Firestore/nosql long. I'm a bit worried about the complexity of this design too. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [offical documentation says](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas), the `Maximum depth of subcollections is 100`. So you don't have to worry about a database structure that has only 4 levels as you mentioned. A normal app has usually a 3 to 4 levels of subcollections.

You can also change all of your subcollections to top level collections but this isn't the case anymore when it comes to Firestore. So regarding Cloud Firestore Scalability, you need to know that it scales completely automatically, meaning you don't need to shard your data across multiple instances.